# How to test a function that receives an event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, chai

Creating tests is new to me. I'm trying to create a test for a function that receives an event. It's an `onChange` call if it matters, and I'm using `chai`.

My function:

```
export function handleChange(event) {
  if (isNaN(event.target.value)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('input can only be a number');

  } else if (event.target.value > 5) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Rating can not be over 5 stars, please try again');

  } else {
    this.setState({starRate: event.target.value});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are applying `event.preventDefault()` to an **input**. There's no 'event' to prevent in this case, so that code is essentially useless.

Second, you are using `event.target.value`, when only `event` is getting passed to your function. You're simply looking for `event.value` in this case.

To pass through the current input, simply pass **[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** as a parameter into the JavaScript function. `this` always refers to the current element.

Here's a working example:

```js
function handleChange(event) {
  if (isNaN(event.value)) {
    alert('The input can only be a number.');
  } else if (event.value > 5) {
    alert('Rating can not be over 5 stars, please try again.');
  } else {
    alert('The input was OK.');
  }
}
```

```html
<input onchange="handleChange(this)">
```

When you enter an input (and then attempt to click off of the input), an `alert()` will be thrown.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: hey thanks for your answer :) 

you are right about the event.preventDefault(), didn't need it.

if I'm loosing the 'target' in 'event.target.value' I simply don't get the event value from the input.

I was looking for an answer that can help me test that function and simulate an event when occurring.

Comment: If you do indeed require `event.target.value`, then you must be adding a click handler to the parent and then delegating. That's an unusual approach, though there's no reason that you can't substitute my code above for that. And what "event" are you trying to simulate for that matter? You're already triggering logic when the input is clicked off of. Are you trying to submit a form? You can just use `.submit()` for that.

Comment: The `event` object has a `.target` property regardless of whether you are using delegated event handlers. The `event` object doesn't have a `.value` property.

Comment: I appreciate that, though I'm not using the `event` object in my example -- I'm passing through a parameter to a function that just so happens to be called `event`. This is what was being doing in the initial question, though I do think that the naming convention may be leading to some confusion in that regard.

Comment: I think you'll find the OP is using the function like `something.addEventListener("change", handleChange)`, because then the use of `event.preventDefault()` and `event.target` make sense. (Though calling `.preventDefault()` on a `change` event doesn't work.) Either that or they're explicitly passing the `event` object to the handler. Otherwise their code makes no sense at all. Having an argument called "event" that is actually a reference to the element and not the event doesn't make sense.